# Puppeteer/Nodejs stops running when browser is minimised

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--window-size=950,340', '--window-position=970,700']});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const url = "https://www.qimai.cn/rank/index/brand/grossing/device/iphone/country/us/genre/6014/date/" + today;
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});

        await page.setViewport({
           width: 1200,
           height: 1000
        });
```

Right now when I minimise the chronium browser, the script will not run and it will pause there until i reopen the browser. I want it to still be able to work and when its minimised so that I could do my own tasks also.

Comment: I think you are looking for a headless option

Comment: Maybe it is worth to report your use case here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4131